# how do I link a button to the webview of another controller having a link that changes based on the cell pressed?

Tags: xcode8, ios11, wkwebview, swift5

I have a button that needs to open a web view on another controller in modally. currently the button executes the code you see below. I would like the button to open the webview directly. the link changes because it is an rss reader and therefore, based on the cell pressed, changes the link of the button that must open the webview.

this is the code that manages the controller that appears after the cell has been pressed

```
class FeedItemWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
var link: String? = nil
var descriptionTesto:String? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  self.textView.text = descriptionTesto
}
@IBAction func apri(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     guard let url = URL(string: self.link ?? "") else { return }
   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)


}



}
```

here is where it manages the controller where I entered the webview

```
class OpenSafariController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func ritornaLista(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

delete the webview controller that is not needed. import SafariServices. here is the code to put on the button

```
@IBAction func apri(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

  let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: self.link ?? "")!)
    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```